# Rails view not displaying the updated database information, information is retrieved like normal in rails console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I have a `Student` model that `has_many` `CustomField` (polymorphic) rows. After adding a couple `CustomFields` to a student in the rails console, I then started up a rails server and navigated to the page that is supposed to display this information, however it is not displaying any of the updated information.

I have a method `get_custom_fields_with_values` that returns a Hash of field names and values.

In the rails console:

```
student = Student.all.first
field_attrs = FieldAttributes.create(name: 'Favorite Color') # => true
student.custom_fields.build(field_attributes: field_attrs, value: 'Blue').save # => true
student.get_custom_fields_with_values # => { 'Favorite Color' => 'Blue' }
```

However, in the view when I make the call to the `get_custom_fields_with_values`, all that is returned is an empty Hash.

I'm using a Postgres database, and inspecting the data inside it shows that all the rows are there, and all the foreign keys are correct.

This is the query that is made when the page is requested:

```
CustomField Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "custom_fields".* FROM "custom_fields"
WHERE "custom_fields"."custom_fieldable_id" = $1
AND "custom_fields"."custom_fieldable_type" = $2  
[["custom_fieldable_id", "34df8e09-148d-5660-bb6c-dd5ca7c9e0ff"], 
["custom_fieldable_type", "Student"]]
```

The database rows:

[image: database rows]

I've restarted the server multiple times, and still only get an empty hash or empty `ActiveRecord::CollectionProxy` object. However, upon restarting the console, it is able to retrieve the fields just fine and I get the expected Hash back. And running the query that is run when loading the page also returns the expected behavior.

I've cleared my browser cache, restarted the browser, and tried multiple browsers all to the same effect. Restarted the server multiple times, and restarted the console multiple times.

The HAML:

```
= bootstrap_panel do |panel|
  - panel.content = capture do
    .panel-heading
      %h2 Custom Fields
    .panel-body
      = @student.get_custom_fields_with_values
```

The function:

```
def get_custom_fields_with_values
  custom_fields.inject(Hash.new) do |h, cf|
    field_name = cf.field_attributes.name
    h[field_name] = cf.value; h
  end
end
```

And all that is being displayed in the panel body:

```
{}
```

But the method call in the console returns:

```
 student.get_custom_fields_with_values
 => {"Favorite Car"=>"Prius", "Favorite Color"=>"Blue"}
```

config/database.yml

```
default: &default
  adapter:  postgresql
  database: <%= Rails.application.secrets.database %>
  host: <%= Rails.application.secrets.database_host %>
  username: <%= Rails.application.secrets.database_username %>
  password: <%= Rails.application.secrets.database_password %>
  port: 5432
  pool: 10

development:
  <<: *default
test:
  <<: *default
staging:
  <<: *default
production:
  <<: *default
```

**SOLVED**

The problem was my database is multi tenanted and rails was looking in the wrong tenant. I added it to the excluded models so it'd look in public, and it fixed the issue.

Comment: Can you post the relevant code involved?

Comment: @Dbz updated it with the relevant view code and added the function code.

Comment: Possible that you are running rails console and actual app in different environment. What is the environment that you are seeing while you run `rails console` ?

Comment: @imechemi Both are in the development environment, I ran both `RAILS_ENV=development rails c` and `RAILS_ENV=development rails s` and got the same results. The development DB is the only populated DB for this app on my machine, so I know they are in the same env.

Comment: What is your config/database.yml look like?

Comment: @imechemi added it to the question

Comment: Can you also add your controller code, esp the part where you initialize `@student` variable. Also, in view, can you try `@student.reload.get_custom_fields_with_values`

Comment: @UtsavKesharwani The problem was my database is multi tenanted, and I didn't add the CustomFields model to the excluded database, so rails was looking in the wrong schema.

Comment: Glad you got it working! Post your solution as the answer so this question doesn't keep showing as unsolved :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that my database is multi tenanted, so rails was looking in the current schema when it should have been looking in the public schema. I just added the CustomFields model to the exclusion list so rails would look in the public schema and that fixed my issue.